# Turn phone on with ADB or Fastboot?

Tags: boot, power-on, command-line

My power button seems to have busted, is there a way I can boot my phone using ADB or Fastboot or some other command line interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When your phone is not turned on it can't have a adb service running (Disregarding the possible technical difficulties it would also be a security issue.)

Try the following instead:
 1. Take out your battery and connect the phone to a charger
 2. Your phone should now turn on.
 3. Insert your battery.

It worked on my current and on my previous phones (ZTE Blade and Huawei U8220) but it may vary by model and manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer as no, even though it wasnt what I was looking for :D I ended up trying what you did with no luck, but then I put the battery back in and held the volume up button at the same time as the power button and wallah!

Comment: So your power button did work?

Comment: Only after holding the volume button concurrently

Comment: Still better than nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Following  solution worked for me:

1. Take your battery out (needs to be a charged battery).
2. Press and hold the "Home" + "Volume Down" button. While holding them down plug in the battery. This should get you into Recovery mode.
3. Press "Volume Down" button to cancel Recovery and it should reboot your phone.

   - With my testing you need to have usb charger connected when you plugin the battery.

**NOTE**: If you have a USB charger connected it may cause boot-loop until you unplug it.

Verified on Samsung Galaxy S3 with broken power button.

Comment: As a sidenote, this also helped me turning on a phone whose power button was broken. Here's what I did - while holding down "Home" + "Volume down", I plugged the wire in. The phone screen turns on momentarily and it recognises the key combination and goes into fastboot mode. There after `fastboot reboot` is all I needed to reboot it

Comment: Worked the same for me too.. thanks a lot.

Comment: I would like to mention that, *"some devices have 'power button' as their button to select a option, so exiting recovery mode will need the power button to be pressed, and since it is busted, it will create further problem...."*

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can turn it on using fastboot.

Enter in fastboot mode, on the prompt type `fastboot reboot`.

Comment: In order for this to work, they would have to be in fastboot. And that would mean that the phone is on. The original question is can the device be powered on my adb or fastboot command line tools. And The answer to that is "no", since the device has to be on for it to listen for any of the commands from those.

Comment: I was able to use this method, combined with the comments on the accepted answer (hold volume up as you plug in to charge - didn't have to take battery out) to power on my phone from an off state. Hope that helps someone else, as it did me!

Comment: This method worked for me as well. In my case, I had to hold the volume down button when plugging in the phone. It entered fastboot (though it wouldn't turn on afterwards). So I ran the command proposed in the answer, and it rebooted successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Put the device in charging. When screen turns alive, remove the battery and within 3 seconds, insert it again. Your phone would boot into Android.