# How can I boot my Nexus S with a broken power button? Can only boot to "Do not turn off target"

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, battery-life

My Nexus S power button has stopped working and Samsung will not honor the warranty. The farthest I've gotten is to the Downloading screen with the yellow work ahead sign, that says "Do not turn off target" and `USB Control Init USB Control Init End`.

My computer does not find the device via the Android SDK.

I looked up this post [Turn phone on with ADB or Fastboot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/turn-phone-on-with-adb-or-fastboot) and others outside of this forum (eg: removing and inserting battery with charger connected), but it does not work for me.

Once I boot it I can use it by plugging a battery charger or cable to turn on the screen.

Is there a way I could boot it?

Comment: What exactly is broken with the power button? Perhaps there is a way to bypass/fix it. And why won't Samsung honor the warranty? This issue seems to be common with the Nexus S.

Comment: It does not work at all. They said it has water damage, but it has never been wet and the square under the battery is perfectly white. Just an easy excuse that they seem to be using a lot. They said it is not repairable, but did not give me a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the methods you've tried, and the ones I've been reading for the past hour, exploit a circuit "bump" that shouldn't even happen in the first place.

If they don't work with your phone, be happy, your phone is not suffering from further defects. Some I'm referencing are:

- Plug your phone to your computer using the USB cable. Remove and add the battery several times to make the phone start booting: [This video](http://youtu.be/ESbllTfne_g) or [this video](http://youtu.be/w-iehKAkZz4).
- [Gently flick (tap) the back of the phone, right under the lens, with a finger.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=19057680&postcount=10)

---

What you should actually do is to repair the phone, it costs a certain amount, but at least you get the problem fixed by professionals and can take preventive measures to prevent this from happening again.

1. To repair, you can use [Nexus S Power Button Repair](http://mobiletechvideos.mybigcommerce.com/nexus-s-power-button-repair/) or other near you.
2. As a preventive measure, to avoid degrading the power button, you can use an app to lock/unlock the phone. With it, you'll give less use to your power button, and in turn it may last longer.

   Even if it gets broken again, with an app, you still have alternative methods of controlling your phone (lock/unlock).

   [Fix Broken Power Button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.destil.fixbrokenpb) by Destil available from Google Play Store.

   [image: Fix Broken Power Button]

   **Note:** An app installed on your phone CANNOT power it on. So, if the power button breaks again, be sure to not let your phone's battery get empty.

Comment: Thanks Zuul. I've already taken it to a repair shop and they said it cannot be fixed :(

Comment: Ordered the fix ($45). Will update on what happens when I get it back :)

Comment: That app will allow you to unlock it without using the power button, but I don't think it will let you turn it on without it.

Comment: @SaintWacko Bad wording, thanks for the heads up! Rephrased the misleading part.

Comment: @zuul I got it back from repair. Unfixable. Great service,communication and all. Will try again in the future if I run into more problems. Will disasemble the phone now and try to learn something with it. The camera will probably end up in my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem with my Nexus S phone after many years of usage.  The power button no longer works, and I believe it is due to wear and tear in my case.  One android app I use is Button Savior.  It provides soft power and volume keys.  Try it if it fixes your problem.

Another option is if you had rooted the phone already, you can remap the keys by modifying the layout files.  I remapped the following kl files. I mapped the search button at the bottom of the screen to go power off or go to airplane mode.  And mapped one of the volume rocker to wake up the phone, as the soft button cannot wake up the screen.

The files modified are /system/usr/keylayout/cypress-touchkey.pl and 
/system/usr/keylayout/mxt224_ts_input.kl. Here are the contents.

mxt224_ts_input_input.kl

```
key 158 BACK   WAKE
key 139 MENU   WAKE
key 217 ASSIST WAKE
key 102 HOME   WAKE
```

cypress-touchkey.kl

```
key 139 MENU   VIRTUAL
key 102 HOME   VIRTUAL
key 158 BACK   VIRTUAL
key 217 POWER  VIRTUAL WAKE
```

I believe I can squeeze a few many years of usage from this phone with this change. Finally, saving money to get a new cel phone is the most viable option for me in the long run. :-)

Comment: Incredibly smart and unordinary approach. Very good and I laughed for a while.

Comment: Thanks, and glad you like the solution. :-)  I got the new Asus Zenfone zoom, and the Nexus S had become a good android development machine.